# NodeJs and db return value

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm newer for nodejs, I try to write my fist nodejs webapp
I want to read from db and display data in html page.

```
router.post("/filtra", function (req,res){
console.log("Hello I'm on the start page");

var criterioFiltro = {
    nominativo : req.body.nominativo,
    settore: req.body.settore
}

console.log(criterioFiltro);

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
})
    .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});


var filtrati;
Persona.findAll().then(persona => {
    filtrati = JSON.stringify(persona, null, 4);
    console.log("rubrica:", filtrati);

});

console.log("rubrica:", filtrati);

/*
if (criterioFiltro.nominativo!= "" && criterioFiltro.settore != "")
{
    filtrati = where(where(rubrica.elencoTelefonico, {nominativo: criterioFiltro.nominativo}), {settore: criterioFiltro.settore}) ; 
}
else if (criterioFiltro.nominativo!= "")
{
    filtrati = where(rubrica.elencoTelefonico, {nominativo: criterioFiltro.nominativo});
}
else if (criterioFiltro.settore != "")
{
    filtrati = where(rubrica.elencoTelefonico, {settore: criterioFiltro.settore});
}
else
{
    filtrati = [];
}
*/


res.render("filtrati", {settori: settori, rubrica: filtrati});
```

});

why after the block

```
    var filtrati;
Persona.findAll().then(persona => {
    filtrati = JSON.stringify(persona, null, 4);
    console.log("rubrica:", filtrati);

});

console.log("rubrica:", filtrati);
```

the variable "filtrati" out of the block

```
    Persona.findAll().then(persona => {
    filtrati = JSON.stringify(persona, null, 4);
    console.log("rubrica:", filtrati);

});
```

is empty?
the first console.log("rubrica:", filtrati); 
print the json file, the second unavaiable
what I wrong?
what can I do to return out the result set of the query?

Comment: Persona.findAll() is asynchronous, so node.js comes through executes it and keeps going on to the `console.log` (even before findAll() returns anything) so `filtrati` is undefined. Inside the `.then()` block is guaranteed to wait for findAll() to finish which has values for `persona` and `filtrati`. Google node.js asynchronous topics

Answer (score 0):

This is very common in JavaScript. You have to call render inside the `.findAll` callback. You can not return value from callback.

Example:

```
Persona.findAll({}).then(persona => {
  // DO YOUR STUFF
  res.render(....);
});
```

Or, since its a promise you can await it like this:

```
const data = await Persona.findAll({});
console.log(data);
```

**REMEMBER:**

To await a function it must return a `promise` and the scope has to be `async` as well. Google ***JS promise async/await*** for details.

Comment: I try the first method and the web page loop to render 3996 records when there are only 8 records to display. The page is without data. If I try the second method
const filtrati = await Persona.findAll();
console.log("rubrica:", filtrati);
there is an error near Persona
Semi-colon expected    JavaScript Problem

Comment: This is probably because you didn't iterate properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to get records and iterate over all records.

```
 let getAllParsonas = async ( req, res, next ) {
   try {
    let foundParsonas = await persona.findAll({});
    if ( foundParsonas ) {
        res.send({'personas':foundParsonas });
        // if you want to ittrate over each record
        foundParsonas.map(pElem => {
          console.log(pElem); // each element from that record array will be display here
           // you can also implement other logic or parse data against keys here. 
        });
      }

    } catch ( err ) {
     console.log(err);
    } 
  };
```